# A little Tic-tac-toe program with the __str__ method, python 3

Tags: python, string, tic-tac-toe

I have to write a Tic-tac-toe program with python and I use Jupyter Notebook. I want to write a class with the `__str__` method. I've first try with a method I've called `afficher`, in the class Terrain. And it seem to work. But when I try with the `__str__` method, it doesn't work.

```py
    class Case:
        def __init__(self, a = ' '):
            self.occupe = a
        
        def jouer1(self):
            if self.occupe == ' ':
                self.occupe = 'X'
            
        def jouer2(self):
            if self.occupe == ' ':
                self.occupe = 'O'
```

*** In need to replace the `affiche` methode by `__str__` methode ***

```py
    class Terrain:
        def __init__(self):
            self.grille = []
            for i in range(0, 9):
                self.grille.append(Case())
            
        self.tour = 1
        
    
        def afficher(self):        
            for i in range(9):
                if (i + 1)%3 != 0:
                    print(self.grille[i].occupe + ' | ', end =" ")
                else:
                    print(self.grille[i].occupe)

                
        def jouer(self, k):
            if self.tour == 1:
                self.grille[k].jouer1()          
                self.tour = 2
            else:
                self.grille[k].jouer2()
                self.tour = 1
```

** this is the output I need, but with the `__str__` method in the class Terrain**

```py
    terrain = Terrain()
    terrain

    terrain.jouer(3)
    terrain.jouer(2)
    terrain.jouer(4)
    terrain.jouer(6)
    terrain.jouer(5)

    terrain.afficher()
```

*** this is how I replace the afficher method in the Terrain class (It doesn't work ... I don't know why ...) ***

```py
    class Case:
        def __init__(self, a = ' '):
            self.occupe = a
        
        def jouer1(self):
            if self.occupe == ' ':
                self.occupe = 'X'
            
        def jouer2(self):
            if self.occupe == ' ':
                self.occupe = 'O'
```

```py
    class Terrain:
        def __init__(self):
            self.grille = []
            for i in range(0, 9):
                self.grille.append(Case())
            
        self.tour = 1
        
    
        def __str__(self):        
            for i in range(9):
                if (i + 1)%3 != 0:
                    return self.grille[i].occupe + ' | '
                else:
                    return self.grille[i].occupe + ' \ '

                
        def jouer(self, k):
            if self.tour == 1:
                self.grille[k].jouer1()          
                self.tour = 2
            else:
                self.grille[k].jouer2()
                self.tour = 1
```

```py
    terrain = Terrain()
    terrain

    terrain.jouer(3)
    terrain.jouer(2)
    terrain.jouer(4)
    terrain.jouer(6)
    terrain.jouer(5)

    print(terrain)
```

Sorry for my english.

Comment: When you `return`, it ends the loop on the very first iteration

Answer (score 0):

Try the following for generating a string for the entire range rather than only one row

```
def __str__(self):
    content = []        
    for i in range(9):
        if (i + 1)%3 != 0:
            content.append(self.grille[i].occupe + ' | ')
        else:
            content.append(self.grille[i].occupe)
    return '\n'.join(content)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much OneCriketeer.
I try this, and it works !

'
def **str**(self):
content = []
for i in range(9):
if (i + 1)%3 != 0:
content.append(self.grille[i].occupe + ' | ')
else:
content.append(self.grille[i].occupe + ' \n')
return ''.join(content)

'